# Regex look ahead for between n and m of a character class anywhere within input

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

What's the regex look ahead that asserts that there is at least n, but no more than m, of a character class within the input.

To make a simple concrete example, suppose I want to assert there are **5-8 digits** somewhere in the input, and the input is comprised of word chars and spaces (ie `[ \w]*`). Then:

```
this line 123 does not match
this line 123 foo 456 matches
this line 123 % 456 does not match
this line 123 foo 456 bar 789 does not match
```

I have tried various combinations of `{5,8}` in a look ahead:

```
^(?=(.*\d){5,8})[ \w]*$
```

but the upper bound of `8` isn't being applied as line 4 above matches (eg on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)).

Comment: I don't think it's possible using one regex, I'd just match all the digits and test the length after.

Comment: @sudo_O I think it's possible, maybe you'll check my answer and downvote if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way. You have to use *two* look aheads - one for the lower bound, and a negative one for the upper bound:

```
^(?=(.*\d){5,8})(?!(.*\d){9,})[\w ]+$
```

Comment: `^(?=(.*\d){5})(?!(.*\d){9})[\w ]+$` is sufficient. The first one asserts `>= n`, the second one asserts `< m + 1`.

Answer (score 4):

`^` From the start of the string, match 0 or more non-digits then digit `{5 to 8 times}` then non-digits only, until the end of the string `$`:

```
^([^\d]*\d){5,8}[^\d]*$
```

Comment: I've tested it, of course, and still fail to see how it fails. Works as requested on all inputs I try. Anyway, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Bohemian just checked at regexpal: 123456 matches, as it should.

Comment: My mistake was making the example in the question too simple. You are right that this matches, but I was looking for a look-ahead. I'll change the question (sorry!)

Comment: @sudo_O Actually this is correct for the question as originally asked, so please remove the downvote. However, I have changed/refined the question to require a look ahead, which is what I want to find out

Comment: Do you use "m" mode with `^` and `$` matching line breaks? Then wrapping my answer in a look-ahead works too.

Comment: I did not know that the `*` quantifier had that effect on the `{n,m}` when used like this, very nice +1.